# How to get the total number of messages sent today in pusher?

Tags: pusher

Is there a way to get the number of total messages that has been sent in real time? I know that the dashboard provides this information, but it's not real time. I'm looking for an api that would return the same data but in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message count stats are not available via an API at present. See http://pusher.com/docs/rest_api for details on the available methods.

You could do some calculations yourself by tracking the calls to the the Pusher REST API and also by tracking the number of subscriptions to the channels you are publishing events on.

See [How is my message count calculated?](http://pusher.tenderapp.com/kb/accountsbillingplanspricing/how-is-my-message-count-calculated).